# Norm of the Dual Transform = Norm of the Transform?

Tags: proof-verification, normed-spaces, linear-transformations

For a continuous (bounded) linear transformation $T$ between vector spaces $T: V \to W$ the dual transformation is defined between their continuous dual spaces as $T' : W' \to V'$ where $T'(w'(v)) = w'T(v)$ for all $v \in V, w' \in W'$.

I'm reading a proof that $||T'|| = ||T||$on p.43 here  https://www0.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/coursematerial/2015/3074/1/B4a_all_lectures.pdf

The proof that $T'$ is a linear transformation is straightforward.

The proof that $||T'|| \le ||T||$ is brief. I understand it as $w'T(v)$ is a scalar valued composition of bounded functions, so that $||w'(T(*))|| \le ||w'||.||T||$. And since $T'(w'(*)) = w'T(*)$ then $||T'(w'(*))|| \le ||w'||.||T||$ which is the condition that $T'$ is bounded and $||T'|| \le ||T||$ (**I think ?**)

The proof then goes on to reference a corollary of the Hahn-Banach theorem to prove that $||T|| \le ||T'||$. This seems to be an overkill to me. **Having established that $T'$ is continuous can one not just reverse the previous argument and get $||T|| \le ||T'||$ ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part is fine.

The problem in reversing the previous argument is, that you use the submultiplicativity of the norm $\def\n#1{\left\|#1\right\|}
$$\n{T'(w')} = \n{w'\circ T} \le \n{w'}\n{T}$
This does not work in the other direction. For $v\in V$, we cannot write $Tv$ as a composition of two linear maps in general.

What you can do (it does not help you to get rid of Hahn-Banach though) is to apply the upper argument again giving $\n{T''} \le \n{T'}$, where $T'' \colon V'' \to W''$ is $T'$'s dual. Then note that 
$$ i_W \circ T = T'' \circ i_V $$
where $i_V \colon V \to V''$ and $i_W \colon W \to W''$ are the natural inclusions. As $i_W$ is (Hahn-Banach!) isometric, we have 
$$ \n{T} = \n{i_W \circ T''} \le \n{T''}\n{i_W} = \n{T''}\le \n{T'} $$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I started to suspect there may be something wrong with my approach when I tried to detail it and couldn't.